# How to Correctly Run Python Script from PHP

Tags: php, python, linux, shell, command-line

I have a python script that I would like to run from PHP. This is my PHP script:

```
$data = array('as', 'df', 'gh');

// Execute the python script with the JSON data
$result = shell_exec('python /path/to/myScript.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));

// Decode the result
$resultData = json_decode($result, true);

// This will contain: array('status' => 'Yes!')
var_dump($resultData);
```

And this is my Python script:

```
import sys, json

# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'status': 'Yes!'}

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)
```

I would like to be able to exchange data between PHP and Python, but the above error gives the output:

> ERROR NULL

Where am I going wrong ?

**:::::EDIT::::::**
I ran this:

```
 $data = array('as', 'df', 'gh');

    // Execute the python script with the JSON data

        $temp = json_encode($data);
        $result= shell_exec('C:\Python27\python.exe test.py ' . "'" . $temp . "'");



    echo $result;
```

I am getting `No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: if you got the solution of this can you share pls

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, the code works perfectly fine and displays:

```
array(1) {
  'status' =>
  string(4) "Yes!"
}
```

On the other hand, you may make a few changes to diagnose the issue on your machine.

1. Check the default version of Python. You can do this by running `python` from the terminal. If you see something like:

   ```
   Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
   [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>>
   ```

   you're fine. If you see that you are running Python 3, this could be an issue, since your Python script is written for Python 2. So:

   ```
   Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
   [...]
   ```

   should be a clue.
2. Again from the terminal, run `python myScript.py "[\"as\",\"df\",\"gh\"]"`. What do you see?

   ```
   {"status": "Yes!"}
   ```

   is cool. A different response indicates that the issue is probably with your Python script.
3. Check permissions. How do you run your PHP script? Do you have access to `/path/to/`? What about `/path/to/myScript.php`?

   Replace your PHP code by:

   ```
   <?php
   echo file_get_contents("/path/to/myScript.php");
   ?>
   ```

   Do you get the actual contents?
4. Now let's add a few debugging helpers in your PHP code. Since I imagine that you are not using a debugger, the simplest way is to print debug statements. This is OK for 10-LOC scripts, but if you need to deal with larger applications, invest your time in learning how to use [PHP debuggers](http://xdebug.org/docs/) and how do use [logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/).

   Here's the result:

   **/path/to/demo.php**

   ```php
   <?php
   $data = array('as', 'df', 'gh');

   $pythonScript = "/path/to/myScript.py";
   $cmd = array("python", $pythonScript, escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
   $cmdText = implode(' ', $cmd);

   echo "Running command: " . $cmdText . "\n";
   $result = shell_exec($cmdText);

   echo "Got the following result:\n";
   echo $result;

   $resultData = json_decode($result, true);

   echo "The result was transformed into:\n";
   var_dump($resultData);
   ?>
   ```

   **/path/to/myScript.py**

   ```py
   import sys, json

   try:
       data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
       print json.dumps({'status': 'Yes!'})
   except Exception as e:
       print str(e)
   ```

   Now run the script:

   ```
   cd /path/to
   php -f demo.php
   ```

   This is what I get:

   ```
   Running command: python /path/to/myScript.py '["as","df","gh"]'
   Got the following result:
   {"status": "Yes!"}
   The result was transformed into:
   array(1) {
     'status' =>
     string(4) "Yes!"
   }
   ```

   yours should be different and contain a hint about what is happening.

Comment: But I want to run it from PHP

Comment: @harvey_slash: I'm unsure how your comment is relevant in the context of my answer.

Comment: how do I run python myScript.py "[\"as\",\"df\",\"gh\"]"  from php ?

Comment: @harvey_slash: I'm sorry, my answer was unclear. I reformulated it.

Comment: ran it from php , your way, it works. But How to get it to work from json_encode() ?

Comment: I tried printing the exception, its just showing NULL

Comment: I removed the escapeshellarg and just wrote json_decode. It shows this error now  : 
string(32) "No JSON object could be decoded "

Comment: I had the "No JSON object could be decoded" Error until I added the quotes around the python scripts argument.

Comment: but its not working for me

Comment: @MainMa, this is what I got: 
Running command: python C:\python27\python.exe test.py "[ as , df , gh ]" Got the following result: The result was transformed into: NULL

Comment: if my script didnt have the correct permissions, how is it returning the error 'json object could not be decoded' ?

Comment: still getting Running command: python C:\python27\python.exe test.py "[ as , df , gh ]" Got the following result: The result was transformed into: NULL

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by adding quotes around the argument!
Like so:
   `<?php
    $data = array('as', 'df', 'gh');
    $temp = json_encode($data);
    echo shell_exec('python myScript.py ' . "'" . $temp . "'");
    ?>`

Comment: doesnt seem to work for me :/

Comment: If you try printing your `data` variable back into PHP instead of your `result` var, does that make it produce anything?

Comment: var_dump gives this:
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "as" [1]=> string(2) "df" [2]=> string(2) "gh" }