# Run python script from PHP in windows

Tags: php, python

I want to run `python` script from `php`. I am on `python 3.5 , 64 bit` .I have read [StackQ1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283065/run-a-python-script-from-the-prompt-in-windows) and  [StackQ2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622526/how-to-correctly-run-python-script-from-php). No one was helpful. I am running this code

```
<?php
$py = exec("D:/pythonFolder/python C:/wamp64/www/python.py");
echo $py;
?>
```

`D:/pythonFolder/python` is the path to `python.exe`. On running the above code, nothing happens. I also tried with this `$py = shell_exec("python C:/wamp64/www/python.py");` and this `$py = exec("python C:/wamp64/www/python.py");` but no success.
Any help will be appreciative.

Comment: Try adding a `$output` parameter to `exec` to check what is emitted.

Comment: @PEMapModder Sorry. I am new in php. `$py` is already a output parameter.

Comment: Why would you expect any output from running `ls` on a Windows machine? And you're using `exec()` function wrong

Comment: Have you checked your command `D:/pythonFolder/python C:/wamp64/www/python.py` if it's working correctly on **cmd**?? Also `$py` will only have *The last line from the result of the command.* ,  you may want to check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture any output from the python script, you need to use shell_exec.  Otherwise you're just running the script and the output isn't going anywhere.  There are different commands for different purposes.  Exec only runs a command, doesn't care about any potential return values.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Comment: I tried this, Nothing happens `$py = shell_exec("D:/pythonFolder/python C:/wamp64/www/python.py");`